# Obtaining coordinate of the top and bottom white pixels in order to draw a line

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap, coordinate

I have the following binary image in bitmap extension:

[image]

Now I would like to:

1. Obtain the coordinate of the top and bottom white pixel (blue mark)
2. Draw a line(yellow line) intersecting those two coordinates (something like the following image)

[image]

I have tried the `at` function, `image.at<uchar>(i,j)` but did not succeed. Would really appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

```
Mat image = imread("Before.bmp");
int i=1;
imshow("Before", image);

vector<Point> locations;   // output, locations of non-zero pixels
cv::findNonZero(image, locations);
Point pnt = locations[i]; /Assertion error

for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++) {
        if (image.at<uchar>(i,j) == 255  ) {
            cout << i << ", " << j << endl; //give wrong coordinate
        }
    }
}

//imshow("black", image);
//imwrite("blackie.bmp", image);

waitKey(0);
return(0);
```

Comment: try switching `i` and `j`, like `image.at<uchar>(j,i)`

Comment: Hi @JeruLuke, thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately that didn't work as well. My current code uses image.at<uchar>(i,j) or (j,i) didn't output the correct coordinate of white pixels. Do you have any idea what caused it?

Comment: How about [`cv::findNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190)? You could probably just run it one the first and last row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DanMašek It outputs an error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in cv::findNonZero. Could it be because the image is in bitmap extension?

Comment: That means that `findNonZero` needs the input to be a single channel image (i.e. grayscale). So just use `cvtColor` to create a grayscale version of your image, and run it on that.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks! It works! But aren't binary images considered single channel since it only has 0 or 255 in a pixel? Could you please explain to me as I couldn't find a proper explanation to this.. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: You're right about binary images. If you look at the documentation of [`imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread), you will notice that it actually takes two arguments. The second argument has a default value `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`. You didn't provide the second parameter, so the default applies, and the function loads the image converted to BRG. Since you eventually want to draw on it in color anyway, I left it as such.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I'm clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cv::findNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaed7df59a3539b4cc0fe5c9c8d7586190) to find the coordinates of any non-zero (i.e. not black) pixels. According to the documentation, this function requires the input to be a single channel image, so you need to first convert to grayscale.

In the following example, I work with an assumption that the white lines go all the way from the top to bottom row, and that on there are exactly two of those lines at the top and bottom edge of the image (like on your image). You might want to extend this to be more flexible.

### Example Code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image(cv::imread("foo.png"));

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(image, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    std::vector<cv::Point> locations[2];

    // Top points
    cv::findNonZero(gray.row(0), locations[0]);

    // Bottom points (need to offset Y since we take a single row ROI)
    cv::findNonZero(gray.row(image.rows - 1), locations[1]);
    for (auto& p : locations[1]) {
        p.y += image.rows - 1;
    }

    // Validate our assumption of having exactly two points on both top as well as bottom row
    if ((locations[0].size() != 2) && (locations[0].size() != 2)) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected input.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i(0); i < 2; ++i) {
        cv::line(image, locations[0][i], locations[1][i], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255));
    }
    cv::imwrite("foo_out.png", image);
}
```

### Example Output

[image]